# regex for check if url have path to file (to use it in laravel 5 validation)

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5.1

How can I determine if an url is created in that format?

```
1. http(s)://XXX.XX --> OK
2. http(s)://XXX.XX/ --> OK
3. http(s)://XXX.XX/test --> OK
4. http(s)://XXX.XX/test/ --> OK
5. http(s)://XXX.XX/sdf.sdfsf --> Fail
6. http(s)://XXX.XX/sdf.sdfsf/  --> Ok
7. http(s)://XXX.XX/test/sdf.sdfsf --> Fail
8. http(s)://XXX.XX/test.test/test/sdf.sdfsf  --> Fail
```

For now I have found that regex:

```
(?:[^\/]*+)$(?<=\..)
```

but have two problem:

- That *I think* this validate (for laravel validation) only if there are a file in path, but I need the exacly reverse.
- That find only a file if have extension with file.x and not file.x{x+}

Any suggestion to correct the regex?

**Update:**

Here the Unit Test (https://regex101.com/r/bV1nS3/1) with:

```
(?:.*\/)(?:[^.]+$)
```

Comment: Not all files have extensions. It is impossible to find out if a path is a directory or a file using only regex. You need access to the operating system in order to find out.

Comment: You should be using apache's .htaccess to achive what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.*\/+(?:(?:XXX\.XX\/*)|[^\.]+)?$
```

Here I took text after last "/" and checked if it has dot. If it has dot then it must be file name else directory. Also you have to mention XXX.XX in regex if you change it.

Comment: Please see the update in the question. I have create the unit test to simplify what the goal of regex.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
(?:.*\/)(?:[^.]+$)
```

You can find your exemple [here](https://regex101.com/r/pN8xH7/1).

Comment: It is the same as `.*\/[^.]+$`m and does not differ from the other answer here.

Comment: Please see the update in the question. I have create the unit test to simplify what the goal of regex.